# ActivityNotFoundException when using Facebook plugin with Unity

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, prime31

I'm using Unity 5.2.2p2, Facebook Unity SDK 7.2.2 and the Prime31's Android IAB plugin 2.9. When I compile my app and run it on a device, in the adb logs I see this:

```
I/Unity   (18149): AndroidJavaException: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.-----.----/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
I/Unity   (18149):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (18149):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticVoidMethod (IntPtr clazz, IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (18149):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (18149):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (18149):   at Facebook.Unity.Mobile.Android.FBJavaClass.CallStatic (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (18149):   at Facebook.Unity.Mobile.Android.AndroidFacebook.CallFB (System.String method, System.String args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (18149):   at Facebook.Unity.
```

However in the Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml file, I've got the following definitions:

```
<activity android:configChanges="locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"/>
</activity>
<activity android:configChanges="locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
<activity android:configChanges="locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
<activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity"/>
<activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity"/>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity"/>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity"/>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity"/>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb1234removed"/>
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234removed" android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"/>
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode" android:name="com.prime31.GoogleIABProxyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

It makes no sense to me. This used to work, and I'm not sure why it doesn't anymore.

Comment: If you remove the IAB plugin, does it build? The manifest that you've included looks fine (though it isn't complete - maybe there's something wrong with some other part of it)? I've used earlier versions of both plugins together successfully before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just want to answer that I've managed to fix it. It's one of those Unity things where you just have to uninstall all your plugins and reinstall them again. Find every single file related to both plugins, delete them, install them one at a time again.

Furthermore, with the new `Smoola` integration in 2.9, if you're not using Smoola, the plugin loads anyway and checks for internet access. This needs the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission which the `Prime31` manifest doesn't include.